# Call Outlook REST API without Consent Window

Tags: rest, outlook, outlook-restapi

Hi All I need to use the Outlook REST API for the research purpose, I suppose to read the inbox messages, There will be no Web, Mobile GUI for the Grant user permissions but In the documentation and every sample tutorial has the consent window approach, Is there way to login and use to REST API without consent window?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, there is a great sandbox available [here](https://oauthplay.azurewebsites.net/). Just sign in with your account, then click on Get Tokens button. After getting the token, you will be able to send API calls! This has helped me a lot!